# Macro in Umbraco work but is gone after second save

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a problem in Umbraco 7 that is when I attach a macro from a Partial View Macro file inside my richtext editor, it disappears from the editor, when I save the content. The content is displayed fine on the page, but when I save the content again, the macro also disappears from the webpage.

My Macro dont have spaces or Special Characters.
De name is ShareContent.
The macro use a partioal view.

Comment: Do you have any custom settings in your `/config/tinyMceConfig.config` file? This sounds vaguely like what happens to HTML you enter into a RTE that is disallowed in the `/config/tinyMceConfig.config` file. Please check your umbraco logs and that config file and add any interesting details you find.

Comment: I have the default tinyMceconfig from version 7.12.3, and i have also recently upgraded to 7.12.3, but in older version it also not work. In the log i cant find error or other thing related to the problem.

Comment: After the first save the maco comment out. <!--?umbraco_macro macroalias="ShareContent" contentid="1947"?-->

Comment: Is your macro configured to try to render within the rich text editor? If so, could you try disabling that option and see if anything changes? Does this happen with all macros? Or is the problem specific to this one macro? If so, could you post some details about the macro and partial view that renders it?